# JButton para conectar a una BD

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

```
JButton Conectar = new JButton("Conectar");
```

en mí clase principal.

Me gustaría que ese botón ejecute otra clase que tengo en el paquete.

GuardarDB que dentro contiene el método Conexion.

Intenté ésto pero no funciona.

```
GuardarDB db = new GuardarDB();
Conectar.addActionListener(db);
```

Luego intenté los derivados que me daba netbeans como "corrección" pero ninguno funcionó.

```
package tallereslaborales;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class GuardarDB {

    static Connection con = null;

    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://jorgemartini.u-host.cl:3306/jorgemar_vilcun";
    static String user = "";
    static String pass = "";


    public static Connection Conexion(){
        PreparedStatement psInsertar;
        Statement stmmt;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            try {
                Socias personas = new Socias();
                System.out.println(personas.getNombre());
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Conexión exitosa a la BD!");

                psInsertar = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO talleres (nombre,rut,taller,telefono,sector)" + " values(?,?,?,?,?)");                

                psInsertar.setString(1,personas.getNombre());
                psInsertar.setString(2,String.valueOf(personas.getNumero()));
                psInsertar.setString(3,personas.getTaller());
                psInsertar.setString(4,String.valueOf(personas.getNumero()));
                psInsertar.setString(5,personas.getTaller());

                psInsertar.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GuardarDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO HAY CONEXIÓN EN LA BD! COMUNIQUESE CON UN ADMINISTRADOR. " + "\n" + "          info@jorgemartini.u-host.cl");
            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GuardarDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return con;
    }


}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo de tu clase `ConexionDB`.

Comment: Primero verifica que las clases que ocupes estén importado :import PackEkemplo.miClase; También verifica que tus métodos o propiedades estén en publicos

Comment: Éste es mí código y se llamaba GuardarDB(no ConexionDB)

Comment: y que error arroja? o que excepción?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer

```
Conectar.addActionListener(db);
```

Le estás pasando una clase y no deberías pasarle eso. Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Conectar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        //Aquí es donde llamas al método de la otra clase.
        //Depende como lo hayas creado tendrás que crear un objeto del tipo de la clase y llamar a su método
        // o si es estático con poner el nombre de la clase y el del método vale
    } 
} );
```

Lo que no queda claro es donde dices "Me gustaría que ese botón ejecute otra clase que tengo en el paquete".

Las clases no se ejecutan, puedes crear objetos de ese tipo o llamar a métodos de esa clase (los métodos sí que se ejecutan).

Comment: Pues me dí a entender mal, el botón Conectar, debería llamar al método Conexion.